# Fetching data from multiple tables, eliminating duplicates values

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch data from two tables in a mysql database.Table 1 contains the name etc., and table 2 contains details (I can't change this given structure).

#### Table 1

```
id   | name   |
7    | Test0  |
8    | Test1  |
```

#### Table 2

```
name_id   | a_id   | value
8         | 1      | detail 1
8         | 2      | detail 2
```

Each detail for a given name in table 1 is stored in a row in table 2. I can fetch data like this:

```
$dbhost = 'host';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pass';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM 
 table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.name_id=table1.id ';

mysql_select_db('database');
$result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $result )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
echo 
"Id: ".$row->id.", Name: ".$row->name.", Attribute: ".$row->value."<br />";
}
mysql_close($conn);
```

The output is:

```
Id: 7, Name: Test0, Attribute:
Id: 8, Name: Test1, Attribute: value 1
Id: 8, Name: Test1, Attribute: value 2
```

But I would rather need something like this

```
Id: 7, Name: Test0, Attribute: 
Id: 8, Name: Test1, Attribute: value 1, value 2, value 3...
```

All details should be shown in one line with the corresponding name.

Any help would be appreciated!

#### Solution:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.value) as value 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.name_id=table1.id
GROUP BY table1.id, table1.name
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `GROUP_CONCAT`, like this:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.value) as value 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.name_id=table1.id
GROUP BY table1.id, table1.name
```

Answer (score -1):

We could achieve it using the below query,

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.value) as attribute 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.name_id = table1.id
GROUP BY table1.id, table1.name
```

Link to usage of group_contact: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Comment: I didn't downvote, so I can't explain it :) Maybe someone didn't like the link that you have added, try to provide links to official pages.

Comment: I'm sorry for the downvote. I didn't do it! I guess, there was a typo in the first version that would have thrown an error. No reason for a downvote in my opinion. Thanks for the help anyway.